# Recording user action to an array with Jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays

I am trying to make a simple user click action recorder in jquery but am having some trouble. I want the user to click a record button then once clicked record what he clicks on. Then press stop button to stop recording. 
What I have so far is:

```
var stack = new Array();
var recordmode = false;

$('#record').click(function(){
recordmode = true;
alert('You are now in record mode');
});

$('#stop').click(function(){
recordmode = false;
console.log(stack);//output what's in the array
stack = []; //erase the array
});


$('#note_markers').click(function(){
if(recordmode){
$('.one_0').click( function(){ stack.push('one_0'); })
$('.one_1').click( function(){ stack.push('one_1') ; })
}
});
```

and later the start and stop buttons.

```
<a id='record'>R</a>
<a id='stop'>stop</a>
                           <div id="one_notes">
                                <a class="one_0"></a>
                                <a class="one_1"></a>
                                <a class="one_2"></a>
                                <a class="one_3"></a>
</div>
```

Also before stopping and erasing the array..I would like to build a URL in the form of /one_0/one_1/one_0 etc with what was in recorded in the array. (haven't got to that part yet though)

What happens is the first click is not recorded and after that it starts putting in two of the same element. I can't figure out why I am getting the current behavior.

Any ideas?

As a side note is there a way to get the name of ANY clicked element?

Comment: Please include more of your html.  What are `#note_markers` and `.one_0`?

Comment: As long as the elements has a name, `$('*').on('click', function() { alert($(this).attr("name")); });` will give you the name of any element.

Comment: `$('*')` is almost always a very bad idea. Use `$(document).on('click', ...)` instead!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're issue is you are getting a click from `#note_markers` and a click from `.one_1` as it bubbles up.

Try this:

```
$('#note_markers a').click(function(){
    if(recordmode)
        stack.push($(this).attr('class'));
});
```

You can alter your event listener to listen on whatever it is you actually need, but this will do what you want based on the supplied html

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try separating the click handlers for each action you want to keep track of.

```
$('.one_0').click( function(){ 
    if(recordmode){
      stack.push('one_0'); 
    }
});

$('.one_1').click( function(){ 
    if(recordmode){
      stack.push('one_1'); 
    }
});
```

That looks like a lot of duplicate code... Lets try clean that up a bit. Why not take it one step further and give all your "recordable" actions the same class with a unique `rel` attribute perhaps...

<sub>Using the more current 1.7+ jQuery syntax.</sub>

```
<a class="recordable" rel="one_1"></a>
<a class="recordable" rel="one_2"></a>

$('.recordable').on('click', function(){ 
    if(recordmode){
      stack.push($(this).attr('rel'); 
    }
});
```

As far as building a URL from the resulting array of actions, you could use JavaScripts `join()` function.

```
var targetURL = _base_url + stack.join('/');
```

---

You can capture clicks on any element with the method mentioned in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10323899/recording-user-action-to-an-array-with-jquery#comment13292157_10323899) above... However I recommend you mark exactly what actions you want to capture no need to capture EVERYTHING...

Comment: separating them did the trick...thank you! I had them all as different classes for other things but I will see if I can use the rel attribute and same classes too.

Comment: Lix, I have 150 or so things I need the user to click on. Is there going to be some overhead doing it the way idrumgood suggested? Both ways work great but idrumgood's is sure a lot less lines of code for me. Can you explain the drawbacks of doing it that way?

Comment: Well his will capture any `<a>` tags that are descendants of the `#note_markers` element.  If you want to do exactly that then its the best way to go.  Personally I like to group elements together and also to be as specific as I can be.  A better selector would have been `a.recordable` (if we are still talking about only `<a>` tags.

Comment: I see what you are saying....I just need to rethink things. Thanks again for your help!